# destructor is called multiple number of times while inserting into map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, destructor

In below code , destructor is called multiple number of times :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;


class abc{

    public:
        abc()
        {
            cout<<"\nconstructor called\n";
        }

        ~abc()
        {
            cout<<"\ndestructor called\n";
        }
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"\nfunction called\n";
        }
};

struct cmp_str
{
   bool operator()(abc a,abc b)
   {
      return 1;
   }
};




int main()
{

map<abc,int,cmp_str> mymap;
abc a;
mymap[a]=5; // destructor is called twice
//mymap.insert(pair<abc,int>(a,5)); // // destructor is called 3 times

map<abc,int,cmp_str>::iterator it=mymap.begin();
mymap.clear();
while(1)
{
//infinite loop added to check number of times destrctor is called before objects goes out of scope
}
return 1;
}
```

I am inserting values in the object using different ways.
one by using insert() function  and other by simple [].
when i insert using mymap[a]=5; then destructor is called twice whereas when i comment this line and use insert() function for insertion then destructor is called thrice.
one destructor can be ignored because of mymap.clear() but why rest of the destructor are invoked.

I have inserted infinite loop just above return , so that i can ignore the destructor called when object goes out of scope.
please help me understanding this behaviours because multiple calls to the destructor is dangerous and could leads to core dump if not handled properly.

Comment: When you use `insert()` there is one more because there is a copy constructor involved when you call the function.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: Actually, I believe it's the object in the temporary `pair` object that we're seeing destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison functor accepts its parameters by value, so there are temporary copies made and destroyed.

It's hard to predict the exact number of temporary objects that will exist, though, due to the copy elision exception to the as-if rule.  It will depend on how good your optimizer is and whether everything gets inlined.

Comment: but constructor is called only once when you execute the program.Even if temporary object are being created then it should display multiple constructor also but this is not happening.

Comment: @user1057741 Add `abc(abc const&) { cout<<"\n copy constructor called\n"; }` to your code. All will be revealed then.

Comment: Praetorian:Thanks :) ..got it

Answer (score 0):

capture by reference in your compare operator instead of having new object created....

```
bool operator()(const abc& a, const abc& b)
```

Comment: I did but it is still creating some temp object...could be some internal functionality of map.